# WP Как оборачивать ссылки элементов меню в теги

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть вот такие кастомные меню создаваемые для `header` `footer`

```
<nav class="bl_nav">
                    <?php wp_nav_menu([
                            'theme_location' => 'header_menu',
                            'container' => false,
                            'fallback_cb' => '',
                            'echo' => 1,
                            'container_class' => '',
                            'menu_class' => 'bl_nav__list',
                            'items_wrap' => '<ul class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                            'walker'  => new Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu(),
                        ]
                    ); ?>
 </nav>
```

function.php

```
add_theme_support('menus');
add_action('after_setup_theme', function () {
    register_nav_menus(array(
        'header_menu' => 'Меню в header',
        'footer_menu' => 'Меню в footer (Быстрые ссылки)',
    ));
});

//// Изменение атрибута id у тега li
add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', 'filter_menu_item_css_id', 10, 4);
function filter_menu_item_css_id($menu_id, $item, $args, $depth)
{
    return $args->theme_location === 'header_menu' ? '' : $menu_id;
}

//// Кастомные классы для li меню
function filter_nav_menu_css_class($classes, $item, $args, $depth)
{
    if ('header_menu' === $args->theme_location) {
        $classes[] = '';
        if ($depth === 1) {
            $classes = [
                'block_tab__item'
            ];
        }
        if (in_array('menu-item-has-children', $item->classes)) {
            $classes[] = 'siblings';
        }

    }

    if ($args->theme_location === 'footer_menu') {
        $classes = [
            'footer_tags__item',
        ];
    }
    return $classes;
}

/// Класс к ссылке меню
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'filter_nav_menu_css_class', 10, 4);
function filter_nav_menu_link_attributes($atts, $item, $args, $depth)
{
    if ($args->theme_location === 'header_menu') {
        $atts['class'] = 'bl_nav__link';

        if ($item->current) {
            $atts['class'] .= ' active';
        }
    }

    if ($args->theme_location === 'footer_menu') {
        $atts['class'] = '';

        if ($depth === 0) {
            $atts['class'] .= 'footer_tags__link';
        }
    }
    return $atts;
}

add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'filter_nav_menu_link_attributes', 10, 4);
/// Класс ul ко второму уровню вложенности меню
add_filter('nav_menu_submenu_css_class', 'filter_nav_menu_submenu_css_class', 10, 3);
function filter_nav_menu_submenu_css_class($classes, $args, $depth)
{
    if ($args->theme_location === 'header_menu') {
        $classes = [
            'block_tab__list',
        ];
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Подскажите, как оборачивать элементы ссылок меню в теги `<span class="link_span"></span>`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У Вас же там есть `Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu` в нем и оберните.

Comment: Спасибо,  нашел, помогло.